# How do I use .loc with groupby so that creating a new column based on grouped data won't be considered a copy?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a CSV file with groups of data, and am using the `groupby()` method to segregate them. Each group is processed by a bit of simple math that includes the use of `min()` and `max()` for a couple of columns, along with a bit of subtraction and multiplication to create a new column of data. I then graph each group. This mostly works okay, but I have two complaints about my code - graphs are individual, not combined as I would prefer; I get "SettingWithCopyWarning" with each group. From my searching, I believe the solution is either with the use of `.loc` or with a better split-apply (and possibly combine) method.
I can do this in Excel, but am trying to learn Python and, while my code is functioning, I'd like to improve it.

```
import os.path
import sys
import pandas as pd

filename = "data/cal_data.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=0) #one line of headers

df['Test']="Model "+df['Model No'] +", SN "+ df['Serial No'].values.astype(str) +", Test time "+ df['Test time'].values.astype(str) # combining several columns into a single column that makes grouping straight-forward, and simplifies titles of graphs. Not completely necessary.

df = df[df.index <= df.groupby('Test')['Test Point'].transform('idxmax')]#drop rows after each max test point

for title, group in df.groupby('Test'):
    x1, x2 = min(group["Test Reading"]),max(group["Test Reading"])
    x4, x3 = max(group["Test Point"]),min(group["Test Point"]) #min is usually zero
    R=(x2-x1)/(x4-x3) #linearize
    
    group['Test Point Error']=100*(group['Test Reading']- (group['Test Point']*R+x1))
    
    ax=group.plot(x='Test Point', y='Test Point Error', title=title, grid=True)
    ax.set_ylabel("% error (+/-"+str(Error_Limit)+"% limit)")
```

output error:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
```

edit- added output from `df.head(20)`, and an image of a couple of plots:

```
 Test Point Test Reading    Test
0   0   0.10453 Model LC-500, SN 937618, Test time 17:20:10
1   20  0.17271 Model LC-500, SN 937618, Test time 17:20:10
2   50  0.27838 Model LC-500, SN 937618, Test time 17:20:10
3   100 0.45596 Model LC-500, SN 937618, Test time 17:20:10
4   150 0.63435 Model LC-500, SN 937618, Test time 17:20:10
5   200 0.81323 Model LC-500, SN 937618, Test time 17:20:10
6   250 0.99252 Model LC-500, SN 937618, Test time 17:20:10
7   300 1.17222 Model LC-500, SN 937618, Test time 17:20:10
8   350 1.35219 Model LC-500, SN 937618, Test time 17:20:10
9   400 1.53260 Model LC-500, SN 937618, Test time 17:20:10
10  450 1.71312 Model LC-500, SN 937618, Test time 17:20:10
11  500 1.89382 Model LC-500, SN 937618, Test time 17:20:10
14  0   0.10468 Model LC-500, SN 937618, Test time 17:31:46
15  20  0.17284 Model LC-500, SN 937618, Test time 17:31:46
16  50  0.27856 Model LC-500, SN 937618, Test time 17:31:46
17  100 0.45609 Model LC-500, SN 937618, Test time 17:31:46
18  150 0.63457 Model LC-500, SN 937618, Test time 17:31:46
19  200 0.81341 Model LC-500, SN 937618, Test time 17:31:46
20  250 0.99277 Model LC-500, SN 937618, Test time 17:31:46
21  300 1.17237 Model LC-500, SN 937618, Test time 17:31:46
```

[image: Screenshot of a couple of the output, individual plots]

Edit/update 7/23/2020:
I made a couple of workarounds that make this work, but I would still appreciate any help. Here is the revised for loop code, writing each group to a new csv file to read later (this way I can add the new column created here), also removing the temporary file if it exists already:

```
if os.path.exists("data/temp.csv"):
    os.remove("data/temp.csv")
for title, group in df.groupby('Test'):

    x1 = min(group["Test Reading"].head(1))
    x2 = max(group["Test Reading"].tail(1))
    x3 = min(group["Test Point"].head(1))
    x4 = max(group["Test Point"].tail(1))
    R=(x2-x1)/(x4-x3) #linearization scalar
    group['Test Point Error'] =100*(group['Test Reading']- (group['Test Point']*R+x1))/(x2-x1)
    file = open('data/temp.csv','a')
    group.to_csv('data/temp.csv', mode="a", index=False, columns=columns, header=False)#, header=True, index=True, index_label=None, mode='w', encoding=None, compression='infer', quoting=None, quotechar='"', line_terminator=None, chunksize=None, date_format=None, doublequote=True, escapechar=None, decimal='.'))
    file.close()
```

Then, reading the temporary csv, I used seaborn (`import seaborn as sns` and `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` to plot multiple groups together, grouped by serial number, 4 subplots per row.

```
df = pd.read_csv('data/temp.csv', header=0)
df['Model/SN']=df['Model No']+" / "+df['Serial No'].values.astype(str)
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='Model/SN', hue='Test', col_wrap=4, sharey=False, sharex=False)

g.map(plt.axhline, y=Error_Limit, ls='--', c='red')
g.map(plt.axhline, y=-Error_Limit, ls='--', c='red')

g = g.map(sns.lineplot, 'Test Point', 'Test Point Error', ci=None)
```

[image]

Sum up- these fixes are not ideal; they are work-around solutions and I still get the "SettingWithCopyWarning" error.

Answer (score 0):

So you are asking for:

1. How to stop setting values to copies.
2. How to create a plot with a subplot for each group in matplotlib.

The "SettingWithCopyWarning" happens because you are creating a column and setting values on each group, which is itself a copy of some rows of the DataFrame. Instead of setting the values on each loop I would store 'Test_Point_Error' on a list of series and [pd.concat(list)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) after exiting for-loop, then add that to the DF.

---Edit---
Try replacing:

```
group['Test Point Error']=100*(group['Test Reading']- (group['Test Point']*R+x1))
```

with

```
error_list.append(100 * (group['Test Reading']- (group['Test Point']*R+x1)))
```

This will append a series for each group, with Indexes matching df.index. When you're done it will have exactly one row of error for each row in df. Therefore after you exit for-loop:

```
df.assign(test_point_error=pd.concat(error_list))
```

Will match each row exactly regardless of any sorting on df.

---end of edit---

The subplotting issue is similar, you are plotting each group separately while looping. If you plot after exiting for-loop then

```
df.groupby().plot(subplots=True)
```

will return what you want.

On a separate topic, I would do away with the string concatenation for 'Test' and do:

```
df.groupby(['Model No', 'Serial No', 'Test Time'])
```

This might make your code a lot faster if there are many rows.

Comment: thank you for the suggestions. I am unsure what the creation of a list of series would look like.

Comment: I tried out the string concatenation replacement - and it did run faster, but I lose all but one group for each serial number. Maybe I need to get your suggestion on the subplots working first (with the list of series, which I'm not sure how to append each new series to this correctly...)