# How to take, individually, the first and last value from groupby columns?

Tags: max, pandas-groupby, min, tail, head

Inside a for loop, I am pulling the first and last value from multiple columns, so that I can use each of these values to create a scalar value that is then mathematically applied to create a new column.
My workaround was to limit the selection to the head or tail of each column, and then turn it into a numeric type (int or float) by using `min()` or `max()`:

```
for title, group in df.groupby('Test'):

    x1 = min(group["Test Reading"].head(1))
    x2 = max(group["Test Reading"].tail(1))
    x3 = min(group["Test Point"].head(1))
    x4 = max(group["Test Point"].tail(1))
    R=(x2-x1)/(x4-x3) #linearization scalar
    group['Test Point Error'] =100*(group['Test Reading']- (group['Test Point']*R+x1))/(x2-x1)
```

There are other problems with the code, but I've attempted to address those in another question ([How do I use .loc with groupby so that creating a new column based on grouped data won't be considered a copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62725942/how-do-i-use-loc-with-groupby-so-that-creating-a-new-column-based-on-grouped-da)).

Comment: Do you want the scalar 'Test Point Error' to be defined for every example or just for every group?

Comment: Hope my answer can help you however it assumes you need the scalar for every example.

Comment: @BorutFlis - The scalar "R" is a single value for each group, and it creates unique values in each row. Your answer below looks promising, but I do not follow the ```+10``` in the calculation for "R"... I'll test it anyway though, and update the post with results. Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry about the +10, I was doing some testing and than forgot to delete it.

Comment: Yes my solution calculates the R for each group, but it is available for every row.

Answer (score 0):

First we groupby the data by Test and use .agg to get the first occurrence of Test_Point and Test_reading. We save grouped df to a new variable df_agg.

```
df_agg=df.groupby("Test).agg({"Test_Reading":["first","last"],"Test_Point":["first","last"]})
```

We flatten the multindex in the columns:

```
df_agg.columns=["_".join(c) for c in df_agg.columns]
```

We make your calculation for R:

```
df_agg["R"]=(df_agg["Test Reading_last"]-df_agg["Test Reading_first"])/(df_agg["Test_Point_last"]-df_agg["Test_Point_first"])
```

We merge the aggregate df to the original one on the value of Test, so that we have R avaible for each example.

```
df.merge(df_agg,on="Test")
```

Now you have the value of R and x1 ... x4 available for all examples and you can run your formula.

```
df['Test Point Error'] =100*(df['Test Reading']- (df['Test Point']*df["R"]+df["Test Reading_first"]))/(df["Test Reading_last"]-df["Test Reading_first"])
```